# File not being saved synchronosly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have written a serilaizer to create a model instance. It requires the request serilaizer field to create a file using the request being sent, save it, execute a system command which has the saved file as one of its argument. I am facing an issue with the saving of the file.

```
def _save_file(input):
    with open(settings.PATH, "w+") as file_handle:
        file_handle.write(input)
```

This is the code I am using to save the file. The problem is that the file gets saved out of order and much later which causes the request to not being able to read the saved file. I am not sure why this is not working sequentially in order. Please help.

Comment: Race condition between different requests?

Comment: @KlausD. I have been testing this locally, with just one request, no parallel requests.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `flush()`?

```
def _save_file(input):
    with open(settings.PATH, "w+") as file_handle:
        file_handle.write(input)
        file_handle.flush()
```

Comment: Tried, same result.

Comment: The file will be flushed when closed by the context manager anyway.